# problema al refrescar comentarios en recursividad

Tags: vue.js, recursión

Tengo un sistema de comentarios recursivos (soporta anidacion infinita de comentarios), puedo generar un comentario perfectamente y elcomponente se refresca.Mi problema comienza cuando quiero hacer un comentario a otro comentario, este comentario se agrega correctamente a la base de datos y si refresco la pagina esta todo en su sitio, pero lo que estoy buscando es que se refresque como lo hace un comentario ordinario.No le encuentro la vuelta.

**post.vue**(padre principal)
descripcion:En este componente tengo 2 componentes hijos que son **comment-form** y **list**

```
<template>
<div class="dos">
                <h1>Comentarios</h1>

                <comment-form @update:comments="comments = $event"></comment-form>

                <list :comments="comments" ></list>
                <infinite-loading @distance="1" @infinite="infiniteHandler" >
                    <div slot="no-more">llegaste al final</div>
                    <div slot="no-results">Sin resultados</div>
                </infinite-loading>
            </div>  
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props:['id'],
        data() {
            return {
               post:[],
               comments:[],
               page: 0,
            }
        },
        mounted () {

        },

         methods: {

             infiniteHandler($state) {
               this.page++
                let url = 'api/comments/get/'+this.id+'?page='+this.page
                axios.get(url)
                .then(response => {
                   let comment = response.data.data
                    if(comment.length){
                        this.comments = this.comments.concat(comment)

                        $state.loaded()

                    }else{
                        $state.complete()
                    }
                })
            },
         }

    }
</script>
```

**list.vue**

```
<template>
<div> 
    <div v-for="comments in comments" :key="comments.id" >
        <item :comments="comments" ></item>
    </div>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:[
        "comments"
    ],
  } 
</script>
```

como ven **list** contiene al componente **item** item.vue se encarga de traer los datos del comentario junto al formulario y si este es un subcomentario le pasa la prop `:comments="comments` a su vez si este comentario tiene respuestas vuelve a llamar al list generando asi la recursividad.

**item**

```
<template>
<div> 

    <div class="comment">
        #{{comments.id}}
        <div v-if="comments.parent != null">
                parent_id = #{{comments.parent_id}}
                <p>{{comments.user.name}} > {{comments.parent.user.name}} </p>  
                <p>{{comments.comment}}</p>
        </div> 
        <div v-else>
             <p>{{comments.user.name}}</p>
             <p>{{comments.comment}}</p>
        </div>
        <comment-form :comments="comments" @update:comments="comments.allreplies = $event"></comment-form>
    </div>

    <div class="reply" v-if="comments.allreplies">

        <list :comments="comments.allreplies"></list>
    </div>

</div>

</template>

<script>

export default {

    props:[
        "comments", 
    ],

}
</script>
```

cuando tengo esta linea :

```
 <comment-form :comments="comments" @update:comments="comments.allreplies = $event"></comment-form>
```

**comments.allreplies**
consigo que se refresque pero no me trae los datos como quiero.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
por ultimo   el formulario lo tengo asi ..

**comment-form**

```
<template>
    <form  method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="response">
    <div v-if="comments != null">
        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" v-model="comments.id">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Comentario:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" id="comment" v-model="newResponse"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Responder</button>
</form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:[
        "comments"
    ],
     data() {
            return {
               currentUser:document.querySelector("meta[name='user-id']").getAttribute('content'),
               errors:[],
               newResponse:'',
               parent_id:'',
               id :this.$route.fullPath.split("/")[1],

            }
        },
        methods:{
            response: function(){
                    var url = 'api/comments/store';
                    axios.post(url,{
                        comment:this.newResponse,
                        parent_id:this.comments ? this.comments.id : '',
                        post_id:this.id,
                        user_id:this.currentUser,

                    }).then(response =>{

                        this.getComments()

                    }).catch(error => {
                        this.errors = error.response.data
                    })
                },
                getComments:function(){

                var url = 'api/comments/get/'+this.id;
                axios.get(url).then(response =>{

                     let newComment = this.comments;
                        newComment = response.data.data

                        console.log('form')
                        console.log(newComment)

                    this.$emit("update:comments", newComment);

                }).catch(error => {
                    this.errors = error.response.data
                })
        },



        },
}
</script>
```

lo que hago en el metodo **getcomments* es reasignar la propiedad comments en **newComment** que me llega del padre para enviar el nuevo array hacia el padre principal **post.vue** lo cual logro correctamente, pero al escribir un subcomentario no logro refrescarlos..

```
 getComments:function(){

                var url = 'api/comments/get/'+this.id;
                axios.get(url).then(response =>{

                     let newComment = this.comments;
                        newComment = response.data.data

                        console.log('form')
                        console.log(newComment)

                    this.$emit("update:comments", newComment);

                }).catch(error => {
                    this.errors = error.response.data
                })
```

dentro de **item** intente en

```
<comment-form :comments="comments" @update:comments="comments.allreplies = $event"></comment-form>
```

reemplazarlo por

```
<comment-form :comments="comments" @update:comments="comments = $event"></comment-form>
```

quitando el .replies pero recibo el error

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "comments"

found in

---> <Item> at resources/js/components/ItemComponent.vue
       <List> at resources/js/components/ListComponent.vue
         <Post> at resources/js/views/Post.vue
           <App> at resources/js/components/AppComponent.vue
             <Root>
```

alguna idea? pero no haberme enroscado mucho..
en resumen necesito que cuando escribo un comentario dentro de otro comentario este se muestre sin tner que refrescar la pagina.

Comment: Me mareo tanto codigo, pero a ver si podemos ponerlo mas claro.. vos le pasas una prop a un hijo.. y queres que cuando esa prop se actualice el hijo haga algo? donde esta el watch respectivo para eso?

Comment: empece esta semana a usar vue.. el watch deberia ponerlo en el componente item?

Comment: mira la documentacion... una vez que pasas una prop, no se actualiza automaticamente, necesitas decirle que la mire

Answer (score 0):

por fin logre resolverlo.... la solucion fue quitar `this.$emit` que emite directamente hacia el padre **post.vue** (cosa que no lograba nunca en un comentario anidado ya que itera entre **item.vue** y **list.vue** hasta que ya no haya mas subcomentarios y para ese momento el padre queda demasiado arriba como para refrescar el nuevo dato,esto es interpretacion mia), lo que tuve que hacer fue usar [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) y reemplazar en el formulario esto:

```
  axios.get(url).then(response =>{

                     let newComment = this.comments;
                        newComment = response.data.data


                    this.$emit("update:comments", newComment);
                    this.$emit("update:replies", newComment.allreplies);

                }).catch(error => {
                    this.errors = error.response.data
                })
```

por esto

```
  axios.get(url).then(response =>{

                     let newComment = this.comments;
                        newComment = response.data.data

                    this.$store.state.comments = newComment

                }).catch(error => {
                    this.errors = error.response.data
                })
```